# data-confirm works for $(document).on(), but not $("body").on()

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

We have two links that are intended to function almost identically - Call a controller, delete a record:

```
// g.js
$("body").on('click', 'a.delete-gene-file', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var gene_id = $(this).closest("td").attr("related-data-id");
    var url = $(this).attr("href") + "?img_for_gene=" + gene_id;
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "DELETE",
        success: function(response) {
            $(".ajax-replace.gene-file").html(response);
        },
        error: function(data) {
            alert(data.responseText);
        }
    });
});

// p.js
$(document).on("click", "a.delete-publication-file", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var row = $(this).closest("tr");
    var pub_id = $(this).closest("td").attr("related-data-id");
    var url = $(this).attr("href") + "/?publication_from=" + pub_id
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "DELETE",
        success: function(response) {
            $(row).hide();
        },
        error: function(data) {
            alert(data.responseText);
        }
    });
});
```

Both of these handlers are attached to links created in the same way in a Rails view:

```
<%= link_to '(-)Remove File', uf,
    :class=> "delete-gene-file",
    :data=> {
        :confirm => "Are you sure you want to permanently delete this file? This cannot be undone."
    }
%>
```

The difference is that the first handler, attached to `body`, will fire in its entirety and THEN ask for confirmation (effectively making the confirmation useless and deleting the record immediately), while the second, attached to `document`, will properly ask confirmation and only fire if the user presses OK.

My naive guess is that there's some voodoo attached to document that UJS uses to fire a confirm wrapped around triggering the handler, and that attaching to body does not allow event bubbling up to document and thus keeps this from integrating properly (hence the `.confirm()` after the `.ajax()`), but I don't have any definitive answers - is there anyone who can shed some light on this?

Comment: concerning `jquery` only can you change the first event handler to `document.body` without quotes rather than `"body"` ?

Comment: Changing it to `document.body` replicates the undesired behavior, deleting and then firing the confirm rather than only deleting if confirmed.